# Matplotlib overlap with alpha

Tags: python, matplotlib, alpha

I'm running into an odd bug with matplotlib when plotting lines with transparency:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(120), range(120), alpha=0.4, color='#0000FF', linewidth=3)
plt.savefig('out.png')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

The saved figure looks like this, which isn't surprising: [image: working as intended]

However, the image in the .show() window looks a little bit different:
[image: working as unintended]

In case it's not obvious, I'm talking about the small dot at ~100, 100 where the line appears to overlap itself. Zooming in on this dot will cause it to disappear, so it seems to be a graphical bug. Aside from making the line solid, does anyone have any suggestions for making this go away?

**Edit 1**:
Here are my specs, in case they matter:

```
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.5.1'
>>> sys.version
'2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]'
```

OS X Yosemite (10.10.5)

Comment: works fine for me with python 3.5 and MPL 1.5.0 (no dot or overlap around ~100,100) even with different zooming levels

Comment: Zooming fixes the issue on my platform too. What OS are you on?

Answer (score 2):

a solution can be to use MPL 1.5.0 since I can't reproduce your bug there

Comment: I upgraded to MPL 1.5.1 (I thought I already had it?), but the bug still appears. I'll add my specs to the OP.